# Why does adding connectycube to android project fail?

Tags: android, kotlin, connectycube

I am adding the Connectycube sources to my Android project as indicated in here: [Connectycube Android](https://developers.connectycube.com/android/?id=create-connectycube-app)

I did the following changes in configuration as it was outlined.

- build.gradle of the whole project

  ```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

  buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
       google()
      jcenter()
       maven {
          url "https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
      }
   }
  dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
  // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
   }

  allprojects {
   repositories {
     google()
     jcenter()
     maven {
        url "https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
     }
    }
   }

      task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
  ```
- build.gradle of the application

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.app2"
      minSdkVersion 26
      targetSdkVersion 28
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
   buildTypes {
   release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- rules.pro'
        }
     }
   }

    dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
      implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
      implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
      implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
      implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.3.1")
      testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.3.1")
      implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.10.2'
      implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.2'
      implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.2'
      implementation("ru.gildor.coroutines:kotlin-coroutines-okhttp:1.0")
      implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.2.1' //Core package
      implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:2.2.1' //Android
      implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-gson:2.2.1' //Fuel Gson
      implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6' //Gson

     implementation "com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-chat:1.8.1"
     implementation "com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-videochat:1.8.1"
     implementation "com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-storage:1.8.1"
     implementation "com.connectycube:connectycube-android-sdk-pushnotifications:1.8.1"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
   }
  ```

The project builds well. However when running the app, the app crashes instantly and I now get the following error whereas before it was fine:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.app2-GGFjPULxWAFkxuGr2o1VpA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.app2-GGFjPULxWAFkxuGr2o1VpA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.app-GGFjPULxWAFkxuGr2o1VpA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Galaxy Nexus API 27 as simulator fixed it. Obviously, the API 26 on Nexus 5x was not working together with it.